# Can I git clone non-bare repositories over http?

Tags: git, http, git-clone, git-bare

I am using lighttpd as my server and trying to clone my repositories over http.

I am facing 2 issues:

1. mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update dosent seem to do the trick, I have to manually run git update-server-info in each repo. Why is that?
2. I am able to clone only bare repositories over http. For non bare it give ".../info/refs.. not found". But I am able to clone a non bare repo by explicitly giving path to .git folder "http:// localhost/repo/.git".

Any way that I get both things working fine or is it something I am doing wrong?

/Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the hook file is executable (`chmod +x`).
2. Using the `.git` directory is correct in this instance.

Comment: 1. Thanks will try and chk
2. So you mean to say if I want to clone a normal repo over http I "must" give path to .git/ and there is no other direct way?

Comment: post-update still wont work! Every time I commit I have to run git update-server-info to fetch the new commit (FYI! I am running git via CYGWIN on Windows)